# How to pass subject value assigned by one component in an another component that opens in a new Tab

Tags: angular

I am using the Behavior Subject to set the value from one angular component(device.component.ts) and upon click i need to open another component(device-detail.component.ts) in a new Tab with the subject value set by another component. But i am getting only the initial value not the updated value.

share-property.service.ts

### share-property.service.ts

This is my service class

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharePropertyService {
  private device = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  selectedDevice = this.device.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setSelectedDevice(device: any) {
    this.device.next(device);
  }
}
```

### device.component.html

```html
  <a [routerLink]="['../deviceDetail']" target="_blank" (click)="setDevice(element)">
          <i class="material-icons">
            double_arrow
          </i></a>
```

### device.component.ts

```js
 setDevice(selecedDevice) {
    this.sharePropertyService.setSelectedDevice(selecedDevice);
  }
}
```

### device-detail.component.ts

```js
import { SharePropertyService } from 'src/services/share-property.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-detail',
  templateUrl: './device-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-detail.component.css']
})
export class DeviceDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  sub;
  constructor(private sharePropertyService: SharePropertyService) {
    this.sub = this.sharePropertyService.selectedDevice.subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;

      this.test(this.data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  test(data) {
    console.log(data, 'called'); // => it return subject value when i do dot open in another tab
  }
}
```

currently when i open device-component in new Tab i am getting null value but i need the value that ist set by device.component.ts.

Comment: A new tab means a new instance of the application, started from scratch, and not sharing the memory of the first instance running in the original tab. Use the URL to pass parameters, instead of passing parameters by storing them in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. now i now the reason ,that why i was not getting the right data. I will try this.